# editing Pivot filters

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

good day:

i have below code:

```
Sub pvtfilttest()

On Error Resume Next

Dim dt As String
dt = Sheets("A").Range("D1").Value
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("[Time].[Month Name].[Month Name]")

.ClearAllFilters
.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=dt
End With

End Sub

where Range("D1") is August or dt = August.
```

Above code runs but somehow all fields under the Month Name filter are selected and not just August.

where am i going wrong?

Comment: First obvious thing to say.. remove `On Error Resume Next` and see if you get an error.

Comment: thanks. did that. getting error 1004.
application-defined or obj defined error. seems like
.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=dt is an issue.
xlcaption = 15 is what comes up

Comment: When I record a macro that adds a filter, I notice that it creates a `.PivotFilters.Add2`, rather than `..Add`. Maybe try that?

Comment: will have a crack. thanks